# "Create a TFX pipeline using templates" giving error "Build Failed. No push access to specified image repository."

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, tfx, skaffold

My team and I are setting up a pipeline in GCP, and we are trying to learn by running a notebook tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/cloud-ai-platform-pipelines. However, when we get to the step where we are creating the pipeline, this error shows up. Please help!

We ran:

```
    !tfx pipeline create  \
--pipeline-path=kubeflow_dag_runner.py \
--endpoint={ENDPOINT} \
--build-target-image={CUSTOM_TFX_IMAGE}
```

And we got:

```
`2021-02-09 08:21:49.170213: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:` 
/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/nccl2/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2021-02-09 08:21:49.170263: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
CLI
Creating pipeline
Detected Kubeflow.
Use --engine flag if you intend to use a different orchestrator.
Reading build spec from build.yaml
Target image gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline is not used. If the build spec is provided, update the target image in the build spec file build.yaml.
[Skaffold] Generating tags...
[Skaffold]  - gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline -> gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline:latest
[Skaffold] Checking cache...
[Skaffold]  - gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline: Not found. Building
[Skaffold] Building [gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline]...
[Skaffold] Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.056MB
[Skaffold] Step 1/4 : FROM tensorflow/tfx:0.26.1
[Skaffold]  ---> 6dd91a0791af
[Skaffold] Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /pipeline
[Skaffold]  ---> Using cache
[Skaffold]  ---> 7882f4facc06
[Skaffold] Step 3/4 : COPY ./ ./
[Skaffold]  ---> 2dbfe44eb3f1
[Skaffold] Step 4/4 : ENV PYTHONPATH="/pipeline:${PYTHONPATH}"
[Skaffold]  ---> Running in b6bbdb97a2df
[Skaffold] Removing intermediate container b6bbdb97a2df
[Skaffold]  ---> d7d56f13fe6d
[Skaffold] Successfully built d7d56f13fe6d
[Skaffold] Successfully tagged gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline:latest
[Skaffold] The push refers to repository [gcr.io/ts-ntnu-v2021-stm-ep3j/tfx-pipeline]
[Skaffold] 06e11ce4eea3: Preparing
[Skaffold] ab1902317977: Preparing
[Skaffold] 1a67ae26cf47: Preparing
[Skaffold] 25e69afdb83b: Preparing
[Skaffold] 2bd41d6594e3: Preparing
[Skaffold] 8e486d328b86: Preparing
[Skaffold] 8f42d0a1a747: Preparing
[Skaffold] 4058ae03fa32: Preparing
[Skaffold] e3437c61d457: Preparing
[Skaffold] 84ff92691f90: Preparing
[Skaffold] 54b00d861a7a: Preparing
[Skaffold] c547358928ab: Preparing
[Skaffold] 84ff92691f90: Preparing
[Skaffold] c4e66be694ce: Preparing
[Skaffold] 47cc65c6dd57: Preparing
[Skaffold] 8e486d328b86: Waiting
[Skaffold] 8f42d0a1a747: Waiting
[Skaffold] 4058ae03fa32: Waiting
[Skaffold] e3437c61d457: Waiting
[Skaffold] 84ff92691f90: Waiting
[Skaffold] 54b00d861a7a: Waiting
[Skaffold] c547358928ab: Waiting 
  [Skaffold] 47cc65c6dd57: Waiting
    [Skaffold] c4e66be694ce: Waiting
    [Skaffold] Build Failed. No push access to specified image repository. Trying running with `--default-repo` flag.
No container image is built.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/tfx", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli_group())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
 File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
 File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/tools/cli/commands/pipeline.py", line 117, in create_pipeline
    handler_factory.create_handler(ctx.flags_dict).create_pipeline()
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/tools/cli/handler/kubeflow_handler.py", line 75, in create_pipeline
    skaffold_cmd)
 File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/tools/cli/handler/kubeflow_handler.py", line 291, in _build_pipeline_image
    skaffold_cmd=skaffold_cmd).build()
  File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/tools/cli/container_builder/builder.py", line 92, in build
    image_sha = skaffold_cli.build(self._buildspec)
      File "/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/tools/cli/container_builder/skaffold_cli.py", line 61, in build
        spec.filename))

RuntimeError: skaffold failed to build an image with build.yaml.
```

**-------- UPDATE ---------**

I've found this in my logs if this helps:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with the recommended additional flag from the error message? "Trying running with `--default-repo` flag."  Did that make a difference?
This looks like a simple permissions error. Are you using one of the GCP AI Platform VMs? Can you confirm (through a notebook or similar) that it otherwise has access to the intended repository?
Judging from the error log, you probably need to create the destination bucket manually, through the GCP UI.

Comment: Thank you for responsing! Yes, didnt make a difference. The notebook is running on a GCP instance, and the account should have all permissions to the Storage. I created the bucket manually, with all permissions, and put its path in the config.py file (as instructed by Tensorflow), but I still get the same error message. The account should have all permissions  in the project environment as well.

Comment: Can you use the notebook to read & write test files at the target location via the Python google_storage library? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Comment: @gruppe3, Have you tried to verify [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) granted to the service account from the attached screenshot, having possibility to push images to the container registry?

Comment: We created a service account with Storage admin role, so permission should not be a problem. We have not tried that yet @SarahMesser, do you know how?

Comment: That error is from Docker (used by Skaffold as the builder).  Could you please confirm that you performed step 2.4 to add the `.../cloud-platform` scope? https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/cloud-ai-platform-pipelines#2_set_up_and_deploy_an_ai_platform_pipeline_on_a_new_kubernetes_cluster

Comment: Yes, we have done it several times as well just to be sure. Could it be something else?

Comment: How did you specify `--default-repo` flag  in prior of building target image?

Comment: After creating an account with the Storage Admin role, are you still getting: "[Skaffold] Build Failed. No push access to specified image repository." ?

Comment: I found a similar issue in `skaffold` repo (for Azure container repo), where it is mentioned that it should be already fixed in `V 1.22.0`. You can take a look at this [link](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/5601#issuecomment-837357747) for your reference. Please try the same in latest version and let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!

Comment: I had this error in a completely different scenario (`skaffold` AWS deploy of `nifi`) and the problem was simply that I wasn't logged in to Docker. #Facepalm